# Divide a large Typescript class into multiple files

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a Typescript class that is getting quite big. To organize it better and avoid cramming it up, I'd like to split it over 5-7 different files based on the page object structure. Currently it looks like this in a single file:

mainAPI.ts

```
const axios = require('axios');
export class API {
  makeAxiosRequest() {}
  doLogin() {}
  getJSESSIONID() {}
  getLoginResponse() {}
  deleteAnUser(userName) {}
  addAnUser(userName) {}
  .,etc
}
```

testFile.ts

```
import mainAPI from mainAPI.ts

await mainAPI.doLogin();
await mainAPI.addAnUser();
await mainAPI.logout();
```

I'm looking to achieve something like this:

mainAPI.ts

```
const axios = require('axios');
export class API {
  //Want the methods from loginAPI.ts, userAPI.ts, purchaseAPI.ts to be a part of this class.
}
```

loginAPI.ts

```
doLogin() {}
doAdminLogin() {}
doMemberLogin() {} etc
```

userAPI.ts

```
deleteAnUser() {}
addAnUser() {}
updateUser() {} etc
```

purchaseAPI.ts

```
addToCart() {}
buyProduct() {}
cancelOrder() {} etc
```

Is there a neat way to go about achieving this? If you have done something similar, please do share. Thank you!

Comment: Do you actually need a class or are you just abusing one as a namespace?

Comment: [This is a repost of a previous question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196424/split-a-typescript-class-into-multiple-files)

Comment: A class, @Phil. ```const axios = require('axios');
export class API {
  makeAxiosRequest() {}
  doLogin() {}
  getJSESSIONID() {}
  getLoginResponse() {}
  deleteAnUser(userName) {}
  addAnUser(userName) {}
  .,100 more functions.,
}```

Comment: Yes @caTS. The question closed even after I sent an edited one. I didn't get any answers, so thought of raising a new one.

Comment: [Be careful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255371/1-user-reposting-same-question-over-and-over), it is frowned upon to open duplicate questions on purpose, and these duplicates will be closed, and eventually some moderator/admin/bot/angel/demon might notice and ban you.